# pyspark pivot without aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to essentially pivot without requiring an aggregation at the end to keep the dataframe in tact and not create a grouped object

As an example have this:

```
+---------++---------++---------++---------+
|  country|   code    |Value    | ids
+---------++---------++---------++---------+
| Mexico  |food_1_3   |apple    | 1
| Mexico  |food_1_3   |banana   | 2
| Canada  |beverage_2 |milk     | 1
| Mexico  |beverage_2 |water    | 2
+---------++---------++---------++---------+
```

Need this:

```
+---------++---------++---------++----------+
|  country|    id     |food_1_3 | beverage_2|
+---------++---------++---------++----------+
| Mexico  |    1      |apple      |         |
| Mexico  |    2      |banana     |water    |
| Canada  |    1      |           |milk     |
|+---------++---------++---------++---------+
```

I have tried

```
(df.groupby(df.country, df.id).pivot("code").agg(first('Value').alias('Value')))
```

but just get essentially a top 1. In my real case I have 20 columns some with just integers and others with strings...  so sums, counts, collect_list none of those aggs have worked out...

Answer (score 4):

That's because your 'id' is not unique. Add a unique index column and that should work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

pivoted = df.groupby(df.country, df.id, F.monotonically_increasing_id().alias('index')).pivot("code").agg(F.first('Value').alias('Value')).drop('index')
pivoted.show()

+-------+---+----------+--------+
|country|ids|beverage_2|food_1_3|
+-------+---+----------+--------+
| Mexico|  1|      null|   apple|
| Mexico|  2|     water|    null|
| Canada|  1|      milk|    null|
| Mexico|  2|      null|  banana|
+-------+---+----------+--------+
```